# AuditD - Log sudo access to /etc/passwd by all commands but never for other files

Tags: passwd, linux-audit

I'm struggling with the following task for AuditD

/etc/passwd should be monitored for any access doesn't matter if a cat or sudo cat is used...ok, easy. BUT I should also prevent auditd to log any other sudo commands that are not used to access /etc/passwd

I'm totally lost at this point. Logging each sudo command by -S execve is easy but only for sudo  /etc/passwd gives me headaches.

Comment: I don't understand that problem. It would be easier if you added to the question what you've already tried doing, which command you're using. For instance, to monitor any processes that accesses a file you can run `auditctl -w /etc/passwd -p rwa`, but I don't know if you've already tried that and what's missing. This command also shows the pid and process name that accessed the file. Also, I don't understand how `sudo` is related, since you say _"doesn't matter if a cat or sudo cat"_.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The filewatch you mentioned was the easy part. What I need now is this: A user who issues this "sudo vim /etc/passwd" or "cat /etc/passwd" etc. shoud be logged...if a user issues a sudo command like this "sudo vim somefile" ...nothing should be logged.

Comment: You can see in the audit log this information in the `auid` field. See [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4409591): _Records the Audit user ID. This ID is assigned to a user upon login and is inherited by every process even when the user's identity changes (for example, by switching user accounts with su -john)._

Comment: Given that `/etc/passwd` will be accessed every time a user runs `ps -fe`, `ls -l`, `top`, etc, do you really want to scan through all of those logs?

Answer (score 0):

The `auid` field in auditlog shows you exactly that. You don't need to audit `execve` calls for that.

From [RHEL Audit System Reference](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4409591):

> auid - Records the Audit user ID. This ID is assigned to a user upon
> login and is inherited by every process even when the user's identity
> changes (for example, by switching user accounts with su -john).

For instance, in the following line you could see that the uid was root, but the **auid** (the original user that ran sudo) was john.

```
$ ausearch -i -k passwd |grep cat
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(10/25/22 14:49:05.149:376) : arch=x86_64 syscall=openat success=yes exit=3 a0=0xffffff9c a1=0x7fffffffe268 a2=O_RDONLY a3=0x0 items=1 ppid=10413 pid=10418 auid=john uid=root gid=root euid=root suid=root fsuid=root egid=root sgid=root fsgid=root tty=pts8 ses=21750 comm=cat exe=/usr/bin/cat subj==unconfined key=passwd
```

In case you missed, the relevant part is: `auid=john uid=root`